# Simulation: Make a surface based on a function, on which a ball can roll (in 2D)

Tags: function, math, graph, simulation, godot

I am looking for suggestions or ideas on a way in what program/how I can create a surface from a function (e.g. y=x^2) and have objects, like a ball, interact with it. This means that a ball could roll down into the middle of y=x^2, where the function would act as static ground.

My final goal is to be able to track the ball's speed.

Is this possible?

I made a simulation in Godot 4 (not the best choice for optimizing probably) where a surface was made by mapping points from a function. This was however very laggy when the I tried mapping a lot of points. It may be that I did it badly and could optimize something, but this is a very niche thing and I'm not skilled enough to make some complicated system.

I am looking for suggestions on where I can achieve this or tips on how to create this kind of simulation (or whether it is even realistically possible).
Thanks!

Comment: There are two parts to this: the mathematics of the physics, and the graphics.  Almost any language could be used for doing the physics.  Godot would be an OK choice for the graphics, although it isn't that complicated of a task, so even Pygame would work.

Comment: Note that a rolling ball has angular momentum which affects the way it rolls down a surface. A 2D model could be used to draw a cylinder or sphere, solid or shell only, each with different physics. I suspect it could start to get complicated once you got into it if you intend to write everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an analytical contact.

*Any* smooth surface defined as `z = z(x,y)` can be used in a contact, as long as the contact normal vector is given also `nx=nx(x,y)`, `ny=ny(x,y)`, and `nz=nz(x,y)`. Also, note that `nx*nx + ny+ny + nz*nz = 1` is a constraint requirement.

The center of the ball is going to be given by offsetting the contact point (given by `[x,y,z]`) by the ball radius `R` along the contact normal direction.

```
cx = x + nx * R
cy = y + ny * R
cz = z(x,y) + nz * R
```

From here it gets much more complicated as you need to take derivatives of vectors to work out the velocity and acceleration of the center of the ball, while applying the no-slip condition.

The velocity of the center of the ball is

```
vcx = R*(nz*ωy-ny*ωz)
vcy = R*(nx*ωz-nz*ωx)
vcz = R*(ny*ωx-nx*ωy)
```

where `[ωx,ωy,ωz]` is the rolling velocity vector of the body.

From there you need the acceleration of the center, and the rotational acceleration vector in order to apply the equations of motion.

=> **Rolling ball dynamics are rather complex** and it is unclear if you have a clear understanding of the math behind this to be able to code a simulation like this. I am not familiar with godot, and how fine-grained you need the code to be, but if it already contains a physics engine, then all you need to do is describe the analytical surface with the function of your choice.'

Remember that a surface is described using *two* parameters, as in `z(x,y)` and not a single one like `y(x)` like you state in your posting.

Answer (score 0):

**First Step:**  Simplify the physics.  I suggest starting with a [mass on a frictionless inclined plane.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mincl.html#:%7E:text=For%20a%20frictionless%20incline%20of,the%20sine%20of%20the%20angle.) and limiting the function to be a straight line ( y = mx + c )

[image]

**Second step:** Do the graphics using your favorite graphics package

**Third Step:**  Loosen the restrictions on the function.  You will need to use calculus to integrate over the instantaneous acceleration on the tangent of the surface.  You can reuse the graphics code you developed in step 2.

**Onward and upwards:**  ( or do I mean downwards?) Improve the physics model.  Begin with adding friction and continue, perhaps all the way to the angular momentum of a rolling ball.

[Here is the C++ code](https://github.com/JamesBremner/so77862179) To enhance the physics modelling, edit the code in `std::pair<double, double> cPhysics::position(double t)`

[image]